# How to put new spin on 'tribes living in the treetops'

Tags: biology, culture, aliens

From the answers I received in my previous question explaining why a humanoid society couldn't live atop giant mushroom caps, I have considered going back to my previous idea of them building their villages in the higher portions of great forests- however I'm looking for a way to keep this from coming across as another Endor or Kashyyk.

I have ruled out giant cacti, because what I have in mind would require much more varieties of animal life than the kind of desert environment cacti grow in. I've considered a large jungle but it might be too hot and/or humid for the fur-covered mammals I envisioned. What can I do?

Comment: Instead of on the trees how about in them. Make large parts of your giant tree is hollow create a complex cave system inside your trees.

Answer (score 2):

A jungle isn't necessarily too hot or humid.

Tropical and subtropical dry forests have longer dry seasons and an average annual temperature of around 20-26 degrees Celsius and 68-80 degrees Fahrenheit. However, the trees are shorter than in rainforests and can also have sparse treetops, but the latter problem is easily solved by having a close by water source which can be used for irrigation.

There's less diversity in life in this sort of forest but mammals are actually quite common to them while their migratory habits are also simultaneously more seasonal.